# Is there a website like blockchain.info but for Monero?

Tags: block-explorer

Is there any website like blockchain.info but for Monero cryptocurrency?

Comment: [here](http://bfy.tw/CA2L)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are many block explorers. But there's a key difference, you can't look up addresses and balances because those don't technically exist on Monero blockchain!

You can decode a specific TX but only if you know in advance the matching address+viewkey or address+TXkey.

Here's a quick list:

- http://moneroblocks.info/
- https://explorer.xmr.my/
- https://monerohash.com/explorer/
- https://xmrchain.net/